# All my files turned green in Visual Studio Code and there is a U next to all the files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for editing my code, and one day it randomly decided to make all my files green. This is very distracting and hurts my eyes, and I can't find any way to disable it. What can I do?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le0mC.png)
I think it is git doing this, but how do you stop it from making files green?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're inside a git repository, VSCode does this to show you that those files are currently untracked / not added.

If you don't care about git, you could just delete the .git folder.

If you do care about it, then go to your `settings.json` and add these lines

```
// Whether git is enabled.
"git.enabled": false,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to normal by searching Untrack in VS Code setting  and then set the GIT Untrack Changes to **"Hidden"**

Answer (score 1):

Go to the VS Code Settings -> Extensions -> Git. From there you can disable "Decorations".

Comment: Feels like blindfolding yourself to a problem to me. Better to resolve the issue, surely.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and in my case, it was solved by restart VS Code

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
*.*
```

in .gitignore file on root project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably created a **hidden** `.git` directory inside your project's folder. This directory contains the Git repository's metadata and configuration, including information about the files and their states.

To see this directory, use `ls -a`. To delete it, use `rm -rf .git`

Additionally, in vscode the untracked files are displayed in green.